# Can't connect to my project with visual studio code and TFS

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops

Well when i enter the token (VSTS Token ) in vs code my project name appear for maybe 3 seconds in the left corner of VS code and then disappear.

I tried to enter this command : "...\TF.exe" workspace
and it launches the edit workspace but i can't click ok.

Any help and thanks

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue?If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your authentication.It could be a problem with your authentication.

From your description, you want to connect to TFS and use token to authenticate. But in the description of the azure repo extension , it is stated that  `If you are connecting to Team Foundation Server, you will only need your NTLM credentials`.

**Team Foundation Server**:
If you are connecting to Team Foundation Server, you will only need your **NTLM** credentials (domain name, server name and password). It is assumed that you have the proper permissions on the TFS Server.

**Azure DevOps Services**:
If you are connecting to Azure DevOps Services, you will need a personal access token (PAT).

[image]

In addition, make sure to run Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 or later. Earlier versions of Team Foundation Server are not supported. This [document](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md) provide a guide and getting Started Videos,please refer to it.